# More Properties of Dropdown options

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I've got a dropdown setup going on in which the user enters an input value, chooses a calculation to perform on that number from a dropdown, then a function displays the result.

What I would like is to add more 'values' to the dropdown, so when an option is selected from the list, it can also, say, display some text stored in the list, or some other information. Right now I can return the selected option's value (.value) and use the option's name (.text) to perform functions, but is there any more data I can add to each selection to be used later?

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function myfunction(form)
{
var i = parseFloat(form.Input.value, 10);
var e = document.getElementById("calculationList");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
form.Output.value = strUser*i;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
Input Number:
<INPUT NAME="Input" SIZE=15>

Make a selection:
<select id="calculationList" onchange="myfunction(form)">
<option></option>
<option value="2">Double It</option>
<option value="3">Triple It</option>
<option value="10">Multiply It By ten</option>
</select>

Output Number:
<INPUT NAME="Output" SIZE=15>

</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you may attach *data* attribute to your options like that:

```
<select id="calculationList">
<option></option>
<option value="2" data-aaa="10">Double It</option>
<option value="3" data-aaa="20">Triple It</option>
<option value="10" data-aaa="30">Multiply It By ten</option>
</select>
```

And later get the content of the attribute:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("calculationList");
dropdown.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-aaa"));
});
```

jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/pzKrr/

Edit:
If you want to implement my solution remove *onchange="myfunction(form)"* from the *select* tag. After that add the following code just after that *myfunction*

```
window.onload = function() {
   var dropdown = document.getElementById("calculationList");
   dropdown.addEventListener("change", function() {
      console.log(dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-aaa"));
   });
};
```